# Renaming files in bulk and in ascending order in CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd, file-rename, batch-rename

I know this question was already asked by someone but I will ask again.
Can someone tell me how to rename in bulk and in ascending order if possible in **CMD**. I already tried renaming in powershell but to no avail. It only let me use once and I need to rename another folder files but to no avail. It didn't let it rename files in another folder. This is the code I use in powershell:

```
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem *.mkv | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('Haikyuu - {0:D2}.mkv' -f $i++)}
```

I'm renaming my anime series per folder and some of my copies have 100+ videos. and somehow you could teach me what each code mean (the code that must use in CMD). The ones I've searched can't understand it in layman's term or doesn't tell the user how it's supposed to work. Thank you in advance. by the way, the folder is placed in an external drive.

Comment: You say, in `cmd`, so you want to have a [tag:batch-file], or a `cmd` one-liner? what do you mean by "ascending order" -- alphabetically or alphanumerically? `cmd` commands are only capable of the former, hence to achieve the latter, you need some amount of code; a clear pattern for the input files would help to reduce the amount of code...

Answer (score 0):

so from the beginning:

**$i**= variable for storing the initial value 1

**Get-ChildItem** = is like "dir" which lists the files and folder under a certain path.

In this  case, it is listing all the files which starts with anything but have the extension .mkv
* indicates wildcard.

**|** = pipeline which passes the output of the first command as an input of the next command.

**%** = ForEach-Object is iterating each object one by one coming from the pipeline.

**$_**= Current pipeline object . Here it is taking each object one by one and renaming it using *Rename-Item*

**-NewName** = is the parameter of the Rename-Item which asks for the new name to pass.

Hope it clarifies your need.

Comment: Rutta I already know the powershell code in some tutorial. I hope you can give me some code that can be use in CMD and teach me how each code where used.

Comment: and can I ask you, why can I only use the powershell code once?

Comment: @BlackSkull you cleary don't understand this powershell code if you think it can only be used once. I'm not sure what you expect to happen and how it fails in a different directory though so it's difficult to guide you.

Comment: @notjustme no. what I mean is, that code, I can only used it once. then when I changed path and my desired name to edit another files in another folder, the powershell gives an  error like: **path/name of file**.mkv doesn't exist. but the name of the file exists tho. I already tried different paths in my external but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I can't rename my video files is there were [brackets] on the filename.
So I use this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.mkv | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("(","").replace(")","") }
```

Which on the same directories, I can access subfolders too to omit brackets and parethesis. then I proceed using the code above in the question to rename my files in every folder. The Reason why I'm doing the 'renaming' per folder is that, each folder is different anime series. but the code above is working. 
if anyone can give me less code than repeating the 'replace' and concatenating it, I will gladly accept and choose that as the best answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the parameter `-LiteralPath` for the source, no prior renaming is necessary.

```
%i = 1
Get-ChildItem *.mkv | 
  ForEach {Rename-Item -LiteralPath "$_" -NewName ('Haikyuu - {0:D2}.mkv' -f $i++)}
```

A hint on sorting, I hope the present numbering of the source files has a constant width, otherwise the result is mixed up as an alphabetic sort (which is inherent to ntfs formatted drives) will sort the number 10 in front of 2.

To check this append the parameter `-whatif` to the Rename-Item command